# pip is pointing to wrong python version - How to correct it

Tags: ubuntu, python

I have 2 Python versions in Ubuntu under `/usr/bin/python (2.7)` and `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`.

I have installed `pip` and `pip3`, but both are pointing to `/usr/bin/python (2.7)`. So, any new module installed is not recognizable if program is executed by setting environment `#!/usr/local/bin/python3.7`

```
ubuntu@ip-10-175-18-90:~$ pip --version
pip 19.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)

ubuntu@ip-10-175-18-90:~$ pip3 --version
pip 19.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Installed pandas library & get below error while invoking same module through sample program. Like, below

```
user@host$ python3.7
Python 3.7.2 (default, Mar  7 2019, 21:40:04)
*"[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'"*
```

How do we enforce `pip` to point it to Python 3.7, instead of Python 2.7